# Where can I find the World's Largest Dungeon Actual Play podcasts

Tags: dnd-3.5e, dungeons-and-dragons, podcast

Back in 2007 I overheard a conversation at my D&D table about a D&D group over in Europe that was releasing a game-by-game podcast in English of their time in the Worlds Largest Dungeon Supplement for D&D 3.5e.

Has anyone heard of the group that released an actual play podcast for World's Largest Dungeon and their adventures there?  If so, where may I find it?

Answer (score 3):

### **For the Record**

The user RobertF answered this is the comments back in May and I am placing it here in the answers in order to preserve the information.

> **World's Largest Dungeon Session**
>
> [www.rpgmp3.com/ipb/forum/90-dungeons-and-dragons-35/](http://www.rpgmp3.com/ipb/forum/90-dungeons-and-dragons-35/)

To download the first episode click **[here](http://www.rpgmp3.com/ipb/topic/5960-worlds-largest-dungeon-session-01/)**